# Why listener setting in service.yml in symfony not working?

Tags: symfony

app/config/services.yml

```
services:    
    myApp.event_listener:
        class: Test\EventListener\MyListener
        tags:
            - { name: myApp.event_listener, event: onDoSomething }
```

namespace Test\EventListener

```
use Test\Event\MyEvent;

class MyListener 
{
    public function onDoSomething(MyEvent $event)
    {
        echo "I m on listener";
    }
}
```

namespace Test\Event;

```
use TEST\Entity\MyEntity;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class MyEvent extends Event 
{
    const DO_SOMETHING = 'event.do_something';

    protected $myEntity;

    public function __construct(MyEntity $myEntity)
    {
        $this->myEntity = $myEntity;
    }

    public function getMyEntity()
    {
        return $this->myEntity;
    }
}
```

From Controller:

```
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
$dispatcher->dispatch(MyEvent::DO_SOMETHING, new Event());
```

Can you guy help why it can't add this event into the listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read the [documentation about event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener) . Depending on the event you want to listen you will need to fix your tag declaration in the service definition. This is an example if you want to listen to a kernel event:

**yaml**

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.exception_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

If you want to listen to a custom event, you need to create an appropriate event class beforehand and maybe using the method attribute of the tag definition, as described in the docs:

> There is an optional tag attribute called method which defines which method to execute when the event is triggered. By default the name of the method is on + "camel-cased event name". If the event is kernel.exception the method executed by default is onKernelException().

If you want to create and dispatch your own event, please read the [documentation about the EventDispatcher component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html#creating-and-dispatching-an-event).

You will need to fix several issues in your code!

the service definition of your event listener should use the tag name **kernel.event_listener** and the name of your event (MyEvent::DO_SOMETHING) which is **event.do_something**:

```
services:    
    myApp.event_listener:
        class: Test\EventListener\MyListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: event.do_something }
```

The method in your listener which would be called without specifying the method parameter is **onEventDoSomething**

```
use Test\Event\MyEvent;

class MyListener 
{
    public function onEventDoSomething(MyEvent $event)
    {
        echo "I m on listener";
    }
}
```

In your controller you should get the dispatcher from the container, create an instance of your `MyEvent` class and pass the entity it (see the Events constructor):

```
/** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
$dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
$event = new MyEvent($myEntity);
$dispatcher->dispatch(MyEvent::DO_SOMETHING, $event);
```

As @Cerad commented: if you want to create a new dispatcher instance you do not need the service definition, but you would need to add the listener to the new dispatcher:

```
// create dispatcher and add listener to it
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
$listener = new MyListener();
$dispatcher->addListener('event.do_something', array($listener, 'onEventDoSomething'));

// dispatch event
$event = new MyEvent($myEntity);
$dispatcher->dispatch(MyEvent::DO_SOMETHING, $event);
```

Comment: I tried using adding method attr but it did not work. It would be great if I can know the exact problem of my code.

Comment: @lordrhodos Notice that for whatever reason a new dispatcher is being created.  This makes the services.yml file irrelevant.  The listener needs to be instantiated and then added to the dispatcher as a listener.  Or the dispatcher needs to be pulled from the container.  You are getting close but not quite there yet.

Comment: @Cerad you are totally right, missed that one. I have updated the answer and hope I got it now ;-)

Comment: @lordrhodos Looking good.  Left out a paren in addListener but other than that it works.  I myself like to actually setup a little test case just to catch all the minor stuff.  I personally don't like to have the word event as part of the event name.  Think it is redundant.  I would have event: do_something instead of event: event.do_something.  But it does not matter.

Comment: @lordrhodos  Great! Its working nicely.

Looks like $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher(); is not working for me but not sure why.
While I used $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher'); It has worked perfectly.
          
Thanks  for your effort.